# Get latest nvidia driver from synaptic package manager for ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, cuda

To use CUDA on my Ubuntu 11.04, I

1. Installed Nvidia drivers from synaptic package manager.
2. downloaded CUDA toolkit and SDK from Nvidia site and installed.

But when I ran installation test `deviceQuery` then I got message

```
CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
```

This problem is discussed in some threads on Stack Overflow and somewhere else and solution suggested is to downgrade toolkit version or upgrade Nvidia drivers. I tried installing latest Nvidia drivers from Nvidia site itself but it created many problems with graphics and I am not able to use CUDA.

How can I get latest drivers from synaptic package manager itself? or there is no way I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

follow this link
http://lbkvutechblog.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-11-10/

I installed nvidia using stop lightgdm method before two years ago...I can't remember the exact way,but try this method.and this method will work for you. if you use synaptic just type nvidia and mark for installation.